# What is the tense of: is located

Tags: past-tense, passive-voice, present-tense

Consider the sentence:

> The shop is located near the bus stand.

Is it  present tense? Doubt is ---- is a helping verb presentence
and located is past tense.

Comment: You would use the present tense (is located) for telling someone how to find the shop. If you were telling a story you might use the past tense (was located). Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, "The phone shop _is_ next to the bus stop" but "The cordwainer's shop _was_ next to the inn where the carrier called".

Comment: He located the boy immediately. Past tense. The shop is located on X street. Present tense. The shop was located on x street. Past tense. The second and third are passives.

Answer (score 1):

The usage of *is located* in your sentence is referred to as a ***false passive*** or a ***stative passive***, where *is located* is used as an ordinary predicate, with *located* serving as an adjective for *the shop*.

> 1. The dog is fed (twice a day).
> 2. The dog is fed (so we can leave now).
>
> ...
>
> Sentences of the second type are called *false passives* by some linguists, who feel that such sentences are simply confused with the passive voice due to their outward similarity. Other linguists consider the second type to be a different kind of passive – a *stative passive* (rarely called *statal*, *static*, or *resultative passive*), in contrast to the *dynamic* or *eventive* passive illustrated by the first sentence. ... 
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_voice)</sub>

So for your sentence, you could leave out the adjective *located*:

> The shop is near the bus stand.

And this you would recognize to be the present tense. The past tense would, of course, use *was* instead of *is*.

Comment: It is the present tense. They also exist in the past tense: X was located at Y. You might want to mention that.